# unable to resolve class net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator error in JasperStudio 6.9.0

Tags: java, groovy, jaspersoft-studio

Compiling an old report which compiles fine in other versions, is not compiling in 6.9.0. It gives below error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
calculator_ReportName_1566901869395_723595: 18: unable to resolve class net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator 
 @ line 18, column 1.
1 error
.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:109)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:140)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportsBuilder.compileJRXML(JasperReportsBuilder.java:212)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction.actionCompile(CompileAction.java:154)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction$1.run(CompileAction.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I have tried fixing the issue by changing the groovy jar used in the IDE by changing the artifacts.xml

```
<artifact classifier='osgi.bundle' id='groovy' version='2.5.8'>
  <properties size='1'>
    <property name='download.size' value='5548387'/>
  </properties>
</artifact>
```

I have tried using groovy-all.2.4.16.jar,  groovy-all.2.4.15.jar,  groovy-all.2.5.8.jar

None of it helps.

Comment: It is not Groovy that is missing. It says it cannot find net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator

Answer (score 0):

**Change** `language="groovy"` **to** `language="java"` 
in your *JRXML file* will resolve your problem.